# How to start with OPC UA -- sampling and collecting data from a PLC device?

Tags: plc, opc-ua, kepserverex

I am expected to design the solution for collecting/processing samples from a PLC device, and working with some control tags of the device. Please, suggest the approach. Sorry for the long question. I will split it to more questions after learning what are the smaller and more reasonable subjects/questions.

The solution for the company is built almost from scratch. There are some PLC devices, and there is a KEPServerEx (**without** the IoT Gateway). The PLC devices are already used through the third party proprietary software. But there is no "bigger framework" for future. From that point of view, I can introduce a modern design, but the budget is restricted.

From what I have learned so far, it seems that the KEPServerEx is a good choice for accessing PLC devices, but I have no hands-on experience with it. It seems to me that the OPC UA should be the choice over the older OPC (DA). I am also aware of the ladder way of working with PLC.

From what I have learned about "IoT Gateway" (which will not be used) for KEPServerEx, the KepServer can set the sampling frequency at the PLC tag level. And also the frequency of transferring the data can be set by IoT Gateway. The IoT Gateway then uses an internal (memory) buffer for storing the sampled values, and the tuples (tagID, value, quality, timestamp) can be read and passed to third party.

What is not clear to me is, how to do that without the IoT Gateway. I assume that it must be a basic operation. Is the (tagID, value, quality, timestamp) generic for working with PLC through any OPC server? Or is it generic only for KEPServerEx, or is it special for the IoT Gateway (optional) plugin?

I have learned that OPC Foundation added recently the Publih/Subscribe mechanism to the OPC UA. Does it require also newer version of KEPServerEx? Or can it be used with any earlier OPC server?

I am fairly experienced in programming and database things. I also have some technical background in industrial sensors, actuators,... However, I have never worked with digital automation in industry.

Thanks, and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the PLC you want to communicate with, and the communication network your devices will be transmitting data on, you need to purchase the appropriate driver package so that KEPServerEX can communicate with it.

For example:

If your PLC is an Omron NJ PLC, and it is on an Ethernet network with the server that KEPServerEX is residing on, you will need to use the "Omron NJ Ethernet" driver in the suite package Kepware offers called the "Omron Suite".

Regarding your question about the IoT Gateway:

> From what I have learned about "IoT Gateway" (which will not be used) for KEPServerEx, the KepServer can set the sampling frequency at the PLC tag level. And also the frequency of transferring the data can be set by IoT Gateway. The IoT Gateway then uses an internal (memory) buffer for storing the sampled values, and the tuples (tagID, value, quality, timestamp) can be read and passed to third party.

This can be done without the IoT Gateway, by using the appropriate aforementioned driver, and then using another driver package to send the PLC data to wherever you would like (ODBC client, SQL Server database, etc.). It depends on what you want to do with the data you are acquiring.

Comment: Say, I will choose sending the data to the SQL database. How the "another driver package" communicates with the driver for the PLC driver? Is there any buffer on the path of the data? Does the PLC driver push the data or is the driver for SQL access responsible for asking for data in real time?

Comment: Again, this depends entirely on your communication network. Are the PLC and SQL Database Server on an Ethernet network? KepServerEX will request the data from the PLC at whatever scan rate you specify for each tag. If you wish to use KepServerEX to then push that data to a SQL Server, then you will need Kepware's "DataLogger" package to push that OPC data to a SQL Server. DataLogger will pull the data from the OPC server (KepServerEX) and push it to a SQL database based on triggers that you specify.

Comment: Does KepServerEX have a buffer for the sampled PLC data? Are the data stored elsewhere until the DataLogger gets them from the OPC server? Or is the sampled record pushed immediately to the DataLogger?

Comment: Check the documentation, or Kepware's website: https://www.kepware.com/en-us/products/kepserverex/

Answer (score 1):

When you talk to a specific device you need to know the protocol that the device uses and those protocols can vary really much.

Sometimes the manufacturer of a device provides an OPC server that shields you from this or as you mention a 3rd party Connectivity server like KepServerEx or Matrikon can be used presenting an OPC interface for your client to use.

I don't know anything about the KepServerEx or your particular requirements but normally an OPC server has a cache where values are stored from which the client can read from alternatively read directly from the hardware. Subscriptions can be configured similarly e.g. frequency, threshold etc.

The protocol from the OPC sever/3rd party to the device determines the frequency in which you can sample values. E.g. some protocols need the device to be polled for values, some are more elaborate.

If you create an OPC client then you are pretty much free what kind of OPC server you connect to whether it is a 3rd party or an OPC server from the manufacturer and having the client storing values whenever items in a subscription changes is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with Visual Studio, then AdvancedHMI may be a possible solution. You did not mention any specific PLCs, but AdvancedHMI includes many PLC communication drivers as part of the free package. This gives you the ability to write VB or C# for transferring the values from the PLCs to a database. The drivers are not OPC drivers, but are designed to be much simpler to use and more efficient.